# Sum up data based on multiple factors in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As you can see, I do have a data frame of different stores with multiple departments (1-99, but varying). I do want to sum up the revenue of all departments for each shop for each week.
Is there a more elegant way than using for loops and if statements? I'm using python with pandas.

Here's a photo of the table :

[image]

```
merged = walmart.merge(stores, how='left').merge(features, how='left')
testing_merged = testing.merge(stores, how='left').merge(features, how='left')
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Store": merged.Store, "Dept": merged.Dept, "Date": merged.Date, "Weekly_Sales": merged.Weekly_Sales, "IsHoliday": merged.IsHoliday,
                    "Type": merged.Type, "Size": merged.Size, "Temperatur": merged.Temperature, "Fuel_Price": merged.Fuel_Price,
                    "MarkDown1": merged.MarkDown1, "MarkDown2": merged.MarkDown2, "MarkDown3": merged.MarkDown3, "MarkDown4": merged.MarkDown4,
                    "MarkDown5": merged.MarkDown5, "CPI": merged.CPI, "Unemployment": merged.Unemployment})
```

Comment: You don't need  loops /if statements. Just use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`

Comment: you want groupby() and sum. please post some code. maybe the head of your dataframe, so we can try our solution on some input variables and the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a group by function like the folowing

```
df.groupby(['departments', 'shop','week'])
```

Documentation : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html